Return string value from enum (EF Core)
I have this model in EF Core 3.1:
public class User
{
   // other properties are omitted
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum UserStatus
{
   Active,
   Inactive
}

Inside my DbContext, I have configured the table so that the string value will be stored for Status column (using the HasConversion() method). The problem is if I return an User object to the client, the value for Status will be either 0 or 1. I want it to be "Active" or "Inactive".

Please [edit] your question to include a specific detailed description of "to the client".

Are you returning JSON from ASP.NET MVC Core API?  If so you need to add JsonStringEnumConverter to JsonSerializerOptions.  See this answer by Andrei to ASP.NET MVC Core API Serialize Enums to String: New System.Text.Json serialization ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0 uses built-in JSON serialization. Use System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter (with "Json" prefix): in services..AddMvc().AddJsonOptions()  Does that answer your question?

If not, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how you are generating your JSON.  Thanks!

I'm trying the solution from Andrei. I will come back with more details if it doesn't work
